# Can Whatsapp sue me for using unofficial services? (location: Romania)

Tags: internet, terms-of-service, dmca, romania

I'm building a desktop app where people can manage their business and one of the features is Whatsapp chat directly into the app. This is not using the Whatsapp official API (their official means of integrating chats into external apps) but it's acting like Whatsapp Web (basically simulates the clicks on the Whatsapp web website) so the Whatsapp servers think i'm sending messages from Whatsapp web.

Why am I not using the official API?

Because it's only enabled for whatsapp business accounts and I want my app to work with normal whatsapp accounts as well.

Can Whatsapp sue me because i'm not using the official means and doing it this "hacky" way instead?

Location: Romania

Answer (score 1):

I’ll give a general answer regarding this type of usage of practically any site

First and foremost, they likely cannot sue you.* Unless there is copyright infringement (eg you use their logo without permission) or direct injury (eg you flood their server with too many requests, rendering it inoperable), they would not have standing for a lawsuit.

However, your idea almost certainly violates any major website’s Terms of Service. As a result, they could—at their own discretion—delete your accounts and data, revoke your access, ban your IP address, etc. Your solution may work in the short term, but since you don’t have a contract with the website, you need to remember that they can deny you service at any time.

- well they could, but they’d probably lose